# Выбор кодировки для MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Начал свой проект, хочется сразу использовать лучшие наработки.

Понял, что одна из `utf8_general_ci` или `utf8_unicode_ci`.
Склоняюсь к `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Но наткнулся на информацию, что это немного уже устарело и стоит использовать `utf8mb4_general_ci` и `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Посоветуйте какую кодировку выбрать для БД.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/5441700 Итог - используйте `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. С базой у вас тоже должно быть установлено соединение в режиме `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: Плюсую utf8mb4, современные движки постепенно переходят на неё. Например, в Laravel 5.4 перешли на utf8mb4 и указали, что она "поддерживает хранение эмодзи в базе данных". Куда ж в современном мире без смайликов-то, а? )) Даже на гитхабе их ввели. А вопрос очень популярный, переведу-ка я пожалуй его на русский.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/5441700

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вольный перевод вопроса [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/5441700).

Обе эти кодировки (`utf8_general_ci` и `utf8_unicode_ci`) работают с символами UTF-8, разница в сортировке строк и их сравнении.

> Заметьте: начиная с MySQL версии 5.5.3 предпочтительнее использовать
>   `utf8mb4`, а не `utf8`. Они обе являются кодировками UTF-8, но более
>   старая `uft8` имеет специфические для MySQL ограничения символов UTF-8
>   выше 0xFFFD.

Сравнение по отдельным параметрам.

**Точность**

- `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` основана на стандарте Unicode по сортировке и
  сравнению строк, который более точно сортирует строки в широком
  диапазоне языков/алфавитов.
- `utf8mb4_general_ci` не реализует все правила сортировки Unicode, что
  зачастую влечёт нежелательный результат в некоторых ситуациях для
  определённых языков/символов.

**Производительность**

- `utf8mb4_general_ci` быстрее в сравнении и сортировке, потому что она
  содержит большое число оптимизаций.

  На современных серверах, это приращение скорости будет всегда, но незначительно. Оптимизации были задуманы во время, когда мощности серверов были значительно меньше сегодняшних.
- `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, которое использует правила Unicode для сортировки
  и сравнения, по-честному использует более сложные алгоритмы для
  точной сортировки для широкого числа языков и при использовании
  спецсимволов. Эти правила принимают во внимание специфические
  соглашения для языка, не всегда сортировки идёт в соответствии с
  "алфавитным" порядком.

В принципе, для группы т.н. "европейских" языков нет особой разницы между строгой сортировкой по Unicode и упрощенной сортировкой `utf8mb4_general_ci`, но несколько различий:

Например, Unicode сортирует "ß" так же как и "ss", и "Œ" как "OE" так же как это делают люди, в то время как `utf8mb4_general_ci` сортирует их как отдельные символы (предположительно как "s" и "e" соответственно).

Некоторые символы Unicode определены как незначимые, что означает, что они не должны влиять на порядок сортировки и сравнение должно переходить к следующему символу. И `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` обрабатывает эти символы корректно.

Для группы неевропейских языков, таких как азиатские языки или языки с другим алфавитом существует гораздо больше различий между сортировкой Unicode и упрощённой сортировкой в `utf8mb4_general_ci`. То, насколько подходит `utf8mb4_general_ci` будет зависеть от конкретного языка. Для некоторых языков разница может быть сильно недостаточной.

**Что же использовать?**

Практически нет смысла предпочитать `utf8mb4_general_ci` по соображениям производительности, потому что на современных процессорах разница не будет играть роль "бутылочного горлышка".

Какая-то разница в производительности может быть в каких чрезмерно специализированных ситуациях и если это ваш случай вы должны знать об этом.

Раньше некоторые специалисты рекомендовали использовать `utf8mb4_general_ci` кроме тех случаев, когда необходима точная сортировка и это важнее проседания производительности. Сегодня больше обращают внимание на точную поддержку интернационализации, чем на незначительное проседание производительности.

И ещё я добавлю, что даже если ваше приложение должно поддерживать только английский язык  - в нём может оказаться ситуация, когда в приложении будут вводиться имена людей и часто вводимые имена должны содержать символы, которые встречаются в других языках, поэтому так важно использовать корректные правила сортировки. Использование Unicode во всех местах, где это возможно, поможет вам разработать более качественные приложения.

Comment: Отлично. Но попутно возник вопрос: в php не могу прописать эту кодировку: setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8mb4');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8 mb4'); Как быть?

Comment: @Dilun7495, функции для работы с многобайтовыми строками отлично обрабатывают 4х байтовый UTF-8 при `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` А можно еще больше команд дать `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');` ;)   С `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');` аналогично должно быть (но тут может быть проблема: разные операционки могут требовать разные локали). **Просто в mysql раньше был урезанный UTF-8, теперь они его сделали более полным (4х байтовым)**.

Comment: Visman, благодарю тебя. Буду пробовать