# C#, MySQL, и знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы

Tags: c#, mysql, кодировка, utf-8

Здравствуйте, скажу сразу, я перерыл весь интернет в поисках ответа на вопрос и ни один из вариантов мне не помог.
Проблема:
Пишу десктопное приложение на C#. Приложение взаимодействует с БД MySQL, расположенной на платном буржуйском сервере *freesqldatabase*.
При попытке записать в таблицу бд значение на русском языке вместо символов пишутся знаки вопроса. Сразу при подключении к бд шлю такие команды:

```
 MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            string[] commands =
              {
                    string.Format("set_client='{0}'", charset),
                    string.Format("set character_set_results='{0}'", charset),
                    "set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'",
                    string.Format("SET NAMES '{0}'", charset)
                };

            try
            {              
                foreach(var x in commands)
                {
                    command.CommandText = x;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

`charset это строка = "utf-8"`.

Пробовал и `utf-8` и `cp1251`, всё равно знаки вопроса. 
Саму БД редактирую прогой *dvForge Studio*. В БД выбраны настройки чарсет `utf-8`, в самой таблице также для полей указан такой чарсет.

Строку перед записью в бд преобразую так

```
  string source = userdata["name"];
            byte[] UTF8encodes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
            string plainText = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(UTF8encodes);
```

Поля в таблицах удалял, пересоздавал заново. Безрезультатно.

Comment: В целом выглядит правильно и вы правильно понимаете уровни. Кодировка базы - кодировка подключения - кодировка полей таблицы - кодировка (файла/строки) на клиенте. Ошибка может быть где-то в том месте, где вы уверенно пишете "кодировка такая-то", но не показываете нам скриншот -- а у вас глаз замылился и не видит, что на самом деле вы не то место показываете нам (и сами не туда смотрите) или не тот символ видите.

Comment: Постарайтесь снизить число звеньев в отладке. Не принимайте строки с сайта, просто запишите строку в файл и прочитайте его или даже захардкодьте в cs-файле (только проверьте кодировку самого файла в [File.AdvancedSaveOptions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/686576/213987), мало ли). Чем пишете -- тут же и читайте, чтобы избежать дополнительных глюков программы для работы с БД. Ну и -- удачной отладки.

Comment: Тут еще момент. Как я тестирую: я прогоняю код по внесению данных в таблицу, и сразу обновляю данные в редакторе бд - вижу знаки вопроса. А если в самом редакторе бд указать русские символы - там они правильно отображаются.

Comment: @AK а какой скриншот например это может быть? Глаз у меня явно замылен, долго бьюсь над этой проблемой

Comment: Например, такой - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYlba.jpg (сделано в Sqlyog)

Comment: Про чарсет utf8mb4 тоже видел инфу в инете по подобным проблемам. Рекомендуете попробовать такую? Я пробовал только utf8 и cp1251

Comment: На so [тоже было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757733/213987). Но нет, пока не рекомендую. У вас проблема явно с *любой* кодировкой, а эта новая может только добавить проблем если у вас старенький ODBC-драйвер (в нём может тоже кстати проблема быть, но вряд ли). Разберитесь сначала со своей проблемой, а потом уже будете выставлять mb4

Comment: всё перепроверил, везде utf8, луч надежды стух

Answer (score 1):

Была аналогичная проблема. Поправил строку подключения и все стало норм.

Было:

```
server=localhost;user=some_user;database=some_db;password=some_pass;
```

Добавил:

```
charset=utf8
```

Стало:

```
server=localhost;user=some_user;database=some_db;password=some_pass;charset=utf8
```

Comment: Не используйте mysql-кодировку utf8, вместо неё нужно использовать utf8mb4. Это касается не только параметров подключения, но и таблиц

Comment: @andreymal по моему у Вас достаточно рейтинга, чтобы иметь право редактировать ответы. ИМХО, есть смысл добавить Ваш комментарий прямо в тело ответа :). По любому ответ полезен и его автор заслуживает  прибавки к "репутации"

Answer (score 0):

Помимо указания кодировки в строке подключения **charset=utf8** нужно обязательно поставить в самой таблице **utf8mb4**. В моём случае даже utf8mb3 не помогало.